# Error when installing Dlib on Windows (for python2)

Tags: python, windows, boost, cmake, dlib

Good afternoon, help me please, I want to install dlib for python on windows, but when I write `python.exe setup.py install` in cmd in dlib dir or `pip.exe install dlib` I have this error:

```
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-2.8.9/Modules/Platform/CYGWIN.cmake:15 (message):
  CMake no longer defines WIN32 on Cygwin!
  (1) If you are just trying to build this project, ignore this warning or
  quiet it by setting CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32=0 in your environment or in
  the CMake cache.  If later configuration or build errors occur then this
  project may have been written under the assumption that Cygwin is WIN32.
  In that case, set CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32=1 instead.
  (2) If you are developing this project, add the line
    set(CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32 0) # Remove when CMake >= 2.8.4 is required
  at the top of your top-level CMakeLists.txt file or set the minimum
  required version of CMake to 2.8.4 or higher.  Then teach your project to
  build on Cygwin without WIN32.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8.9/Modules/CMakeSystemSpecificInformation.cmake:36 (INCLUDE)
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED):
  CMake 2.8.12 or higher is required.  You are running version 2.8.9
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
error: cmake configuration failed!
```

I try to update cygwin's cmake with Cygwin installer, but `setup.py` use the old version of cmake (2.8.9). I try to run `setup.py` from cygwin's console, but it doesn't see a Boost (But it installed on my computer). I have this error in cygwin:

```
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Could NOT find Boost
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.3.2/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake:168    (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "/cygdrive/c/dlib-19.4/tools/python/C:/Python27/include/patchlevel.h"
cannot be read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /cygdrive/c/dlib-19.4/dlib/cmake_utils/add_python_module:75 (FIND_PACKAGE)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (include)
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-  3.3.2/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonLibs: Found unsuitable version "", but required is at
  least "2.6" (found C:/Python27/libs/python27.lib)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.3.2/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:386   (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.3.2/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake:205   (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  /cygdrive/c/dlib-19.4/dlib/cmake_utils/add_python_module:75 (FIND_PACKAGE)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (include)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
error: cmake configuration failed!
```

Can I update cygwin's cmake for using it in cmd or make the cygwin's terminal to see Boost?

Answer (score 1):

If you have anaconda you can try this

conda install -c menpo dlib=18.18

I had a lot of problems, when I tried to install it with pip, but with anaconda it was ok

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do this

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I do not think well, but I have an problem with Anaconda. When I try to run conda.exe I have this error.

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)

I have Windows 7, x32 and 2.7 python. I read about this problem in GitHub, but all ways to solve it don't work with me. Please, help me.